# SQS Java client exception - com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a java (AWS Java SDK 1.11.313) SQS consumer polling a queue every 20 seconds which has been running for nearly a week. Over this time it has failed on two occasions, both times throwing the following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Permission denied: connect
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2033)
        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2009)
        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1485)
        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1460)
        at net.myCompany.messageHandlers.QMessageHandler.receiveMsg(QMessageHandler.java:112)
        at net.myCompany.MessageHandler.receiveDirectMsg(MessageHandler.java:23)
        at net.myCompany.commandProcessors.QCommandProcessor.run(QCommandProcessor.java:23)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy9.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1236)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
        ... 14 more
```

On both occasions the client recovered after ~15mins. The method below is responsible for creating and sending the receive request. The exception arose on the `sqs.receiveMessage()` method call above the for loop. Each time a request is sent a new instance of `com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS` is created and assigned to the `sqs` variable.

```
List<JSONObject> receiveMsg() {

        List<JSONObject> cmdMsgList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            if(sqs != null) {
                System.out.println("Attempting message receive at: " + Instant.now());
                // Receive messages
                ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(commandQUrl);
                receiveMessageRequest.setWaitTimeSeconds(20);
                receiveMessageRequest.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
                List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
                for (Message message : messages) {
                    JSONObject msgBody = checkTargetDevice(message);
                    if (msgBody != null) {
                        cmdMsgList.add(msgBody);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ServiceManager.getInstance().setServerConnection(false);
                ServiceManager.getInstance().setConnectionStatus("Can't receive message - Message channel does not exist");
            }

        } catch (QueueDoesNotExistException mia) {
            ServiceManager.getInstance().setServerConnection(false);
        }catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            if(ServiceManager.getInstance().isDebug()) {
                ase.printStackTrace();
                ase.getErrorMessage();
            }
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            if(ServiceManager.getInstance().isDebug()) {
                ace.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return cmdMsgList;
}
```

I thought maybe too many connections were being created and not closed properly however after using netstat it doesn't seem excessive with only a few tcp connections for that program. I have since added the `sqs.shutdown()` call before the return statement however I'm not expecting much change since the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) states that this method call on the `AmazonSQS` interface *is an optional method, and callers are not expected to call it*.

Any insights or advice on this problem is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same non periodic issue during polling data from aws SQS.I added time delayed to call aws SQS and this issue resolved.As below in JAVA.

```
final ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = 
    new ReceiveMessageRequest(sqsURL)
    .withMaxNumberOfMessages(1)
    .withWaitTimeSeconds(6);
```

Hope this will resolved this issue.